# Autofixture generate custom list

Tags: refactoring, autofixture

Here's my object:

```
public class Symbol
{
   private readonly string _identifier;
   private readonly IList<Quote> _historicalQuotes;

   public Symbol(string identifier, IEnumerable<Quote> historicalQuotes = null)
   {
      _identifier = identifier;
      _historicalQuotes = historicalQuotes;
   }
}

public class Quote
{
    private readonly DateTime _tradingDate;
    private readonly decimal _open;
    private readonly decimal _high;
    private readonly decimal _low;
    private readonly decimal _close;
    private readonly decimal _closeAdjusted;
    private readonly long _volume;

    public Quote(
        DateTime tradingDate,
        decimal open,
        decimal high,
        decimal low,
        decimal close,
        decimal closeAdjusted,
        long volume)
    {
        _tradingDate = tradingDate;
        _open = open;
        _high = high;
        _low = low;
        _close = close;
        _closeAdjusted = closeAdjusted;
        _volume = volume;
    }
}
```

I need an instance of Symbol populated with a list of Quote.

An in my test, I want to verify that I can return all quotes which the close price is under or above a specific value. Here's my test:

```
[Fact]
public void PriceUnder50()
{
    var msftIdentifier = "MSFT";
    var quotes = new List<Quote>
    {
        new Quote(DateTime.Parse("01-01-2009"), 0, 0, 0, 49, 0, 0), 
        new Quote(DateTime.Parse("01-02-2009"), 0, 0, 0, 51, 0, 0), 
        new Quote(DateTime.Parse("01-03-2009"), 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0), 
        new Quote(DateTime.Parse("01-04-2009"), 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0)
    };

    _symbol = new Symbol(msftIdentifier, quotes);


    var indicator = new UnderPriceIndicator(50);
    var actual = indicator.Apply(_symbol);

    Assert.Equal(2, actual.Count);
    Assert.True(actual.Any(a => a.Date == DateTime.Parse("01-01-2009")));
    Assert.True(actual.Any(a => a.Date == DateTime.Parse("01-04-2009")));
    Assert.True(actual.Any(a => a.Price == 49));
    Assert.True(actual.Any(a => a.Price == 10));
}
```

OK.

Now, I wanna do it using Autofixture, im a real beginner. I've read pretty much everything I could on internet about this tool (the author's blog, codeplex FAQ, github source code). I understand the basic features of autofixture, but now I wanna use autofixture in my real project. Here's what I tried so far.

```
var msftIdentifier = "MSFT";

var quotes = new List<Quote>();
var random = new Random();
fixture.AddManyTo(
    quotes,
    () => fixture.Build<Quote>().With(a => a.Close, random.Next(1,49)).Create());
quotes.Add(fixture.Build<Quote>().With(a => a.Close, 49).Create());

_symbol = new Symbol(msftIdentifier, quotes);

// I would just assert than 49 is in the list
Assert.True(_symbol.HistoricalQuotes.Contains(new Quote... blabla 49));
```

Ideally, I would prefer to directly create a fixture of Symbol, but I don't know how to customize my list of quotes. And I'm not sure that my test is generic, because, in another test, I will need to check that a specific value is above instead of under, so I'm gonna duplicate the "fixture code" and manual add a quote = 51.

So my questions are:

1 - Is it the way how I'm supposed to use autofixture?

2 - Is it possible to improve the way I use autofixture in my example ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AutoFixture was originally build as a tool for Test-Driven Development (TDD), and TDD is all about **feedback**. In the spirit of [GOOS](http://amzn.to/VI81bP), you should **listen to your tests**. If the tests are hard to write, you should consider your API design. **AutoFixture tends to amplify that sort of feedback**, and here's what it's telling me.

**Make comparison easier**

First, while not related to AutoFixture, the `Quote` class just *begs* to be turned into a proper **Value Object**, so I'll override `Equals` to make it easier to compare expected and actual instances:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as Quote;
    if (other == null)
        return base.Equals(obj);

    return _tradingDate == other._tradingDate
        && _open == other._open
        && _high == other._high
        && _low == other._low
        && _close == other._close
        && _closeAdjusted == other._closeAdjusted
        && _volume == other._volume;
}
```

(Make sure to override `GetHashCode` too.)

**Copy and update**

The above attempt at a test seems to imply that we're lacking a way to **vary a single field while keeping the rest constant**. Taking a cue from functional languages, we can introduce a way to do that on the `Quote` class itself:

```
public Quote WithClose(decimal newClose)
{
    return new Quote(
        _tradingDate,
        _open,
        _high,
        _low,
        newClose,
        _closeAdjusted,
        _volume);
}
```

This sort of API tends to be very useful on Value Objects, to the point where I always add such methods to my Value Objects.

Let's do the same with `Symbol`:

```
public Symbol WithHistoricalQuotes(IEnumerable<Quote> newHistoricalQuotes)
{
    return new Symbol(_identifier, newHistoricalQuotes);
}
```

This makes it much easier to **ask AutoFixture to deal with all the stuff you don't care about** while explicitly stating only that which you care about.

**Testing with AutoFixture**

The original test can now be rewritten as:

```
[Fact]
public void PriceUnder50()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var quotes = new[]
    {
        fixture.Create<Quote>().WithClose(49),
        fixture.Create<Quote>().WithClose(51),
        fixture.Create<Quote>().WithClose(50),
        fixture.Create<Quote>().WithClose(10),
    };
    var symbol = fixture.Create<Symbol>().WithHistoricalQuotes(quotes);
    var indicator = fixture.Create<UnderPriceIndicator>().WithLimit(50);

    var actual = indicator.Apply(symbol);

    var expected = new[] { quotes[0], quotes[3] };
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

This test only states those parts of the test case that you care about, while AutoFixture takes care of all the other values that don't have any impact on the test case. This makes the test more robust, as well as more readable.

Comment: +1 @Gui and others Mark is too polite to flag it but his [PluralSight Advanced Unit Testing](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=advanced-unit-testing) course is chock full of this sort of goodness. Worth paying for but even better they have a free trial and a I cant think of a better course to use it on (though of course [Outside In Test Driven Development](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/outside-in-tdd) is a close second)

Comment: @Mark Seemann Thanks for your comment Mark. I agree your test is definitely more readable. I was planning to ask some more questions, but your answer is so complete, it keeps answering each one of my questions each time I re-read your answer. Omg, you're probably the god of unit tests.

Comment: How about adding extension methods for the `WithClose`, `WithLimit` *defined in the test project*, instead of adding them as instance methods? (now in C#6, they do not even need to be in static classes)

Comment: @BjörnAliGöransson You could, but why would you deliberately keep something away from the 'production code' that obviously benefits the design?

Comment: @MarkSeemann It certainly benefits the readability of the test code, but who knows if it improves the production code? I'm just thinking that maybe the production code doesn't need the shorthand of setting just that property, in favor of something else, for example Object Initializers.

Comment: @BjörnAliGöransson Don't Object Initializers require that the properties are writable?

Comment: @MarkSeemann Oh - you're right. The constructor also cripples the use of object initializers ... How about named parameters, as a kompromiss? In any case, I just wanted to suggest that I didn't see any use case for those convenience methods in the production code - just in the tests ...

Comment: @BjörnAliGöransson How would named parameters help?

Comment: @MarkSeemann I'm just asking: How would those convenience methods help in production code when it's not confirmed that they are needed?

(my suggestions are really just fluff and may be discarded)

Comment: @BjörnAliGöransson If they're helpful when writing tests, they're probably helpful in production code as well. [The tests are the *first* client of the production API](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/11/10/TDDimprovesreusability).

Comment: @MarkSeemann I'd vote against. YAGNI. It also makes the process of refactoring/renaming properties more cumbersome and prone to creating discrepancies between the `Prop` and `WithProp()`, should one forget to rename also the method, so less such things in production code, the better.

Comment: Note. A while after writing this, and despite my initial worries about YAGNI, I found myself going on the line of @MarkSeemann.