# How do I auto-generate objects containing a readonly list using AutoFixture?

Tags: c#, autofixture

I have a class that conceptually looks like this:

```
public class Entity
{
    private readonly List<double> _values = new List<double>();

    ...

    public List<double> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return _values;
        }
    }
}
```

In a unit test, I want to use AutoFixture to provide a list of random entities:

```
var entities = this.fixture.CreateMany<Entity>().ToList();
```

However, no autogenerated values are added to the Values property of the Entity objects, as I would have expected (hoped...). I have tried to change the list of values to not being readonly and add a setter to the Values property, which solves the problem, but isn't there a better alternative to this?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808755/specifying-readonly-property-values-via-ctor-args-when-instantiating-immuta/57202205#57202205

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AutoFixture doesn't fill read-only collections, but you can ask it to do so:

```
var entity = fixture.Create<Entity>();
fixture.AddManyTo(entity.Values);
```

Answer (score 2):

When I discovered this limitation, I went ahead and created an AutoFixture extension to do just this: [Murph.AutoFixture.AutoReadOnlyCollectionProperties](https://bitbucket.org/kbhutchinson/murph.autofixture.autoreadonlycollectionproperties). Publicly available on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Murph.AutoFixture.AutoReadOnlyCollectionProperties/) as well.

While building an object, for any public, read-only property or field whose type implements `ICollection<T>`, it will use the fixture to create a list of T and then call the collection's `Add()` method for each one. It will respect the fixture's `OmitAutoProperties` setting, and also provides an extension method, `WithoutEx()` that emulates the built-in `Without()` (which won't work with read-only properties or fields).

Usage is as easy as you'd expect:

```
fixture.Customize( new AutoReadOnlyCollectionPropertiesCustomization() );
fixture.Customize< Model >( c => c.WithoutEx( m => m.Collection ) );
```