# Autofixtures "With"-Customizations for are ignored when using Build<T>

Tags: c#, autofixture

My goal is to be able to define only the parameters that are relevant for the specific tests, with immutable types in c# (strictly constructor injection, no set'ers), and have a customized fixture take care of valid values for  parameters that is not specified in the test.

Scratching my head over this one - my "with" property-customations for strings, DateTime's and int's are disregarded. Example based on "Guest":

```
public class Guest
{
    public readonly string GuestId;
    public readonly string GivenName;
    public readonly string SurName;
    public readonly AgeCode AgeCategory;

    public Guest(string guestid, AgeCode ageCategory, string givenName, string surName)
    {
        AgeCategory = ageCategory;
        GivenName = givenName;
        SurName = surName;
        GuestId = guestid;
    }
}
```

I customize a Fixture instance like so:

```
        fixture.Customize<Guest>(composer =>
            composer
                .With(g => g.GivenName, "Finn")
                .With(g => g.GuestId, "1")
                .With(g => g.SurName, "Rasmussen")
            );
```

...Which works when using `fixture.Create<Guest>()`, but not when using `fixture.Build<Guest>().With(g=>g.Surname, "Olsen")`.
[image]

Looking at the AutoFixture signatures, i understand this is because `Fixture.Build<T>()` instantiates a new composer, and that composer is not injected as the 'composer' instance of the `Customize<T>` method.
Also - I understand that the first customization for a property "wins", so "overwrites" would have to be pushed in front of the customizations...

Any suggestions? Am I completely of track here, trying to use a screwdriver to hammer a nail? Or am I simply not seeing something clever and/or obvious here...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28362898/126014

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/20816487/126014

Comment: Thanks Mark, and thank you for your great work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else finding this: 
The default strategy for building a type can be changed with

```
Fixture.Register<TType>(Func<TType> creator)
```

Works like a charm...